# Sum rainfall over last 60 days in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm preprocessing weather data where each row is one day with temp, wind, rainfall, etc. I'd like to compute the total rainfall in past 60 days for a new column.

It seems like [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) is close: I could get the rainfall 60 days ago, 59 days ago, etc. I could possibly create 60 series objects and sum them this way but it feels like there's probably a better way.

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If df is your Pandas DataFrame where each row contains values for temp, wind, rainfall, etc., then you can get a rolling 60 day total as follows:

```
pd.rolling_sum(df, 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think rolling windows is what you need. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: true. i was just a little bit lazy to include code without sample data.